# ruby system command failed inside of my code, but works outside of my code independently

Tags: ruby, system

The following is my code of system command call. It works well if I execute it independently outside of my codes, but it does not work if I put it inside of codes. Is there some thing wrong with my code?

```
dakota_file=Plugin.dir + "Dakota_EnergyPlus_cygwin.in"
begin
run_dakota_thread = Thread.new { system("Dakota","#{dakota_file}") }
rescue =>e
UI.messagebox("Thread raised #{e.class}: #{e.message}")
end
```

dakota_file is the path of input file and Dakota is the program I'd like to call.

Comment: What error do you get ? You can replace `system("Dakota","#{dakota_file}") ` by `puts \`Dakota #{daokta_file} 2>&1\`` to return error output

Comment: Ok. I will try. SketchUp based on which I developed, will result some error when using the command shell. Some other programmers also  have met this errors. I will try your advice method and analysis the errors output. Many thanks.